# Call block with call not work

Tags: crystal-lang

I try to use code from this [issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/3943#issuecomment-275620281)

```
def call(&block)
  block.call(3, "test")
end

call do |x, y|
  puts x
  {x, y}
end
```

But only get error:

> wrong number of block arguments (given 2, expected 0)

Is it ok, maybe there is some other way to call block?

Playground link: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/4t8h

Github issue: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/6597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these two forms:

```
def call(&block : Int32, String -> {Int32, String})
  block.call(3, "test")
end

result = call do |x, y|
  {x, y}
end

result # => {3, "test"}
```

or

```
def call
  yield 3, "test"
end

result = call do |x, y|
  {x, y}
end

result # => {3, "test"}
```

And some additional info can be found [here.](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/blocks_and_procs.html)

Comment: Can you describe why? The only thing I see different in your first example from OP's is the signature on `block` - so is it a new bug where inference failed and concluded `block` is nullary despite `block.call(3, "test")`, or a known issue, or a design decision (and if so, documented where)?

Comment: @Amadan see this comment: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/6597#issuecomment-415707981i

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree with "Maybe an untyped block argument shouldn't have a default type but rather be a syntax error if it is used as a proc. This would more clearly describe the error than failing because of mismatched arguments."